# How to change referrer link?

Tags: javascript

How to convert this [link 1](http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgu.com%2Fp%2F4dqfm%2Ffb&h=VAQHJLcqT&enc=AZPaThEaRTCX-l4-p7IhnG-fLwffa6Gc29biVbxjLL_bwGigUa4xy6V1OwJKFCslcpd0qbSIDYtTBVOEovtYW2k2B37re6-kaQuraywUr_DNQcEm5MG8Cc9ODb8hfOZ5CuNoTYvIT7VxpMSwHDS1k-eChZ9vc3USJLAsoB0ZmFBOZmFQKd6o8n_SKadD6295xn5d6Q7_URlDDqw-7pjapUuZ&s=1) to the destination [link 2](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/nov/07/cate-blanchett-carol-film-interview?CMP=fb_gu) with `Javascript`. The second link is the actual destination of the original link[1](http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgu.com%2Fp%2F4dqfm%2Ffb&h=VAQHJLcqT&enc=AZPaThEaRTCX-l4-p7IhnG-fLwffa6Gc29biVbxjLL_bwGigUa4xy6V1OwJKFCslcpd0qbSIDYtTBVOEovtYW2k2B37re6-kaQuraywUr_DNQcEm5MG8Cc9ODb8hfOZ5CuNoTYvIT7VxpMSwHDS1k-eChZ9vc3USJLAsoB0ZmFBOZmFQKd6o8n_SKadD6295xn5d6Q7_URlDDqw-7pjapUuZ&s=1).

Update: I am given the link in the first link form, but I want it in the second form because I need to get Ajax request with the second link form.

1. [original link](http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgu.com%2Fp%2F4dqfm%2Ffb&h=VAQHJLcqT&enc=AZPaThEaRTCX-l4-p7IhnG-fLwffa6Gc29biVbxjLL_bwGigUa4xy6V1OwJKFCslcpd0qbSIDYtTBVOEovtYW2k2B37re6-kaQuraywUr_DNQcEm5MG8Cc9ODb8hfOZ5CuNoTYvIT7VxpMSwHDS1k-eChZ9vc3USJLAsoB0ZmFBOZmFQKd6o8n_SKadD6295xn5d6Q7_URlDDqw-7pjapUuZ&s=1)
2. [actual link](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/nov/07/cate-blanchett-carol-film-interview?CMP=fb_gu)

Comment: what do you mean by converting..? do you want to change the `href` attribute of an anchor tag...?

Comment: No. The ```href``` should be the same. I am given the first link and I want it in the second form.

Comment: Let me get this right, do want to extract the `u` query from Facebook's link?

Comment: Yes. I want the link after ```u```

Comment: @Zip, that's what I meant.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yes. I want to extract that link. But the problem is that that link is changing dynamically on Facebook. So the next link might be ```balbla.org/helloworld/foo.html```. How can I extract such links from the form of the first link(from Facebook)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extract the full link, because The Guardian provides a shortened URL. The best thing you can do is to extract the shortened URL using `substr` and then apply `decodeURIComponent`:

```js
function extractFacebookUrl(u) {
    u = u.substr(u.indexOf('l.php?u=') + 8); // remove before ?u=
    u = u.substr(0, u.indexOf('&')); // remove after &

    return decodeURIComponent(u);
}

var link = "https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgu.com%2Fp%2F4dqfm%2Ffb&h=VAQHJLcqT&enc=AZPaThEaRTCX-l4-p7IhnG-fLwffa6Gc29biVbxjLL_bwGigUa4xy6V1OwJKFCslcpd0qbSIDYtTBVOEovtYW2k2B37re6-kaQuraywUr_DNQcEm5MG8Cc9ODb8hfOZ5CuNoTYvIT7VxpMSwHDS1k-eChZ9vc3USJLAsoB0ZmFBOZmFQKd6o8n_SKadD6295xn5d6Q7_URlDDqw-7pjapUuZ&s=1";

document.body.innerText = extractFacebookUrl(link);
```

It returns `http://gu.com/p/4dqfm/fb`, which leads to the actual page.
Note that it supposes that original link has always the same format and the order of GET arguments.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. I was wrong. Nice job!

Comment: Will this work for any links or just the above link? Because my links are changing dynamically. The next link might be ```randomdomain.io/hello/yes.html```.

Comment: @Zip Of course, it should work. It will output any URL specified in `?u=` GET argument.